# Importing XML document into Django's (postgres) database

Tags: python, django

I have an XML document and i need to import it into Django's database (postgres). I guess first of all is this possible and if so how do i go about doing it?

I'm new to Python / Django and i remember importing a load of models into a db a while ago when running a command in the python shell and was wondering if there was something similiar?

I have a model setup for the content to go in. I just want to be able to import a XML document as there are thousands of items to be added.

Thanks

Comment: This one is pretty broad, and will probably be closed unless you add more specific information. First, look at http://lxml.de/ for parsing.

Comment: You're going to need to include a snippet of the XML document for anyone to even begin to offer a particular solution.

Comment: Why would I? XMl documents are pretty much all the same arn't they? I only want to know how to import them. It's a pretty straight forward xml document and all the models already exist.

Comment: http://cutter.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/generateDS.html#examples-and-demonstrations This does what you want I think. Takes XMl and creates models from it.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I'm trying to do the same thing you tried to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django isn't a database.

Basically, your options are:

1. If the XML is in the format that django uses for fixtures, write models that match that data, and load it as fixtures: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures
2. If you're almost in a position to do 1, you could use XSLT or some other transformer to fix it up for that purpose.
3. Create your own custom program to extract data, and create models as a result. You'll still need to create your models.
4. Use an XML database, and hook it up to django.

Comment: Thanks, I shall take a look at the documentation.

Comment: I'd have to say I recommend 3 so long as you are comfortable with parsing XML objects. I doubt the XML is in a Django-friendly format. Also XSLT has a steeper learning curve than Python in my experience.

Comment: I can't say i've done it before. Is there any documentation I could take a look at to do this? (Sorry I really am new to this so any help would be great!)

Comment: @JoshDavies Option 1 is the same as matg's answer. Option 3 isn't a pre-canned task. Just write a programme that creates an object with fixed data (look at the django docs), work out how to parse your XML into an object (check out lxml.de - it's a good library, but no-one can tell you how to parse a format they don't know), and put the two together.

Comment: @Marcin Regarding point 1 everything I see re XML in django leads to that initial_fixtures doc. Looking for continuous fixtures really to continually update database with xml. Done lxml tutorial, not really sure how to shape data so that django will be able to manage it though.

Comment: @sayth Feel free to ask your own question about that. However, as I say, django isn't a database. There's no reason you need to use xml.

Answer (score 1):

Have you written a model for the data stored in the XML document?  Assuming that's the case, this page in the django docs should help:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures

Comment: Yes, I have a model all setup, I'd just like to import all the fields from the XML document into the model fields.

Thanks, I will take a look now.

Comment: It doesn't have an example for the xml format, but you could add a single instance manually, then dump it in xml format to see how django expects the data to look.

Comment: And if you need a decent xml parser, to go the route of writing code yourself to read the xml and add django objects, I would recommend BeautifulSoup.